# Android Sliding Menu Fragment launching fragment over

Tags: android

The idea is that i want a transparent FragmentActivity placed over the view. I've accomplished that with the list they click on is:

```
case 3:
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginUsingLoginFragmentActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
break;
}
```

Now once they click this a Facebook FragmentActivity login appears and they have the option to login. However when this launches i'd like the sliding menu to close and the FragmentActivity to appear or the sliding menu close while the FragmentActivity loads so that it appears seamless. I'm using the facebook sdk, sliding menu, and Action bar sherlock in case it matters.